# How to declare variable with type x and interface y?

Tags: actionscript-3

eg, if i have an Object that extends *Sprite* and Implements *Mungable* i would like to do something like:-

```
var foo:Sprite <mungable>
```

so that i can do something like:

```
addChild(foo);
foo.munge();
```

Is this possible in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. As others suggested, you can create a type, say `MungableSprite`, that extends `Sprite` and implements `Mungable` and then refer to that type. However you will only be able to use this for objects, who's type is a subtype of `MungableSprite`.

But you cannot simply convey the type relationship "an object, which is Mungeable and a Sprite".

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

In AS3 you cannot have multiple inheritance but Interfaces are quite common.

For your interface, create an actionscript file called **IMungable.as**

```
package
{
    public interface IMungable
    {
        function munge():void;
    }
}
```

For your custom sprite, create an actionscript file called **MyFoo.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MyFoo extends Sprite implements IMungable
    {
        public function MyFoo()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function munge():void{
            trace("munging");
        }
    }
}
```

Then anywhere else, just create a new instance and call the method.

```
            var foo:Sprite = new MyFoo();
            addChild(foo);
            IMungable(foo).munge();
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. What a pain in the Ass actionscript is

Comment: @fakeAccount22: Then you should consider using haXe instead. There are [plans](http://code.google.com/p/haxe/issues/detail?id=271) for supporting this (I suppose bumping up the issue on the mailing list would help :)). However the actual problem here is not as3, but the flash player API. If there were an `ISprite`, you could define an `IMungableSprite` that any class could implement at will.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can simply cast your variable to the interface.

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite implements IMungable {
    public function munge() : void {
        // this is the interface function to implement
    }
}

var foo:Sprite = new MySprite() as Sprite;
IMungable(foo).munge();
```

You may also cast to `MySprite` to call `munge()`.

Comment: In Java for example you can declare the variable as being both types, thus not needing the cast - that's pretty much the point of Interfaces. That's what i want to know how to do. Thanks.

Comment: Not possible in Actionscript, you have to cast. you may have `var foo:* = new MySprite();` for an untyped variable.